# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-chrome, styles

I'm about to make a random background color javascript code. So when you refresh the page, all element's background color will change, but in Chrome, I got an error :

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined"

Here's my JavaScript and HTML :

```js
var colors = [
    [
        [65], [131], [215]
    ], [
        [217], [30], [24]
    ], [
        [245], [215], [110]
    ], [
        [135], [211], [124]
    ]
];
//Getting a random color 
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

var block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
var obj;
for (obj in block) {
    if (block.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {

        block[obj].style.background =
            "rgb" + "(" + colors[random][0] + ", " + colors[random][1] + ", " + colors[random][2] + ")";
    }
}


document.getElementById('body').style.background = "rgb" + "(" + colors[random].r + ", " + colors[random].g + ", " + colors[random].b + ")";
```

```html
<a href="#">
<li class="block block1">
 <i class="icon-vcard"></i>
 <h3>Contact us</h3>
 <content>
 <h3>Contact us</h3>
 <p>
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p>
 </content>
</li>
</a>
<a href="#">
 <li class="block block2">
 <i class="icon-users"></i>
 <h3>Staff</h3>
 <content>
 <h3>Staff</h3>
 <p>
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p>
 </content>
</li>
</a>
<a href="#">
 <li class="block block3">
 <i class="icon-wrench"></i>
 <h3>Tools</h3>
 <content>
 <h3>Tools</h3>
 <p>
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p>
 </content>
</li>
</a>
<a href="#">
 <li class="block block4">
 <i class="icon-info"></i>
 <h3>About us</h3>
 <content>
 <h3>About us</h3>
 <p>
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p>
 </content>
</li>
</a>

</ul>
```

Comment: block is an array and you are treating it like an object. Try using for ( i=0; i<block.length; i++) loop instead of for (i in block) loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the blocks with a for...in, which also causes you to iterate over the "length" property.

A better approach:

```
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

for (var i=0;i<blocks.length;i++) {
        blocks[i].style.background =
            "rgb" + "(" + colors[random][0] + ", " + colors[random][1] + ", " + colors[random][2] + ")";
}
```

Comment: Just to explain why `length` is catched there also as property: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns array-like object `HTMLCollection` instead of real array; for standard array for..in will work correctly returning only values (until some properties will be added there), but it's bad way to do so.